# How to duplicate each character in a string

Tags: python, string, function

How would I repeat a every character in a string twice?

### Expected Output

```
input_string = "hello"

output_string = "hheelllloo"
```

### My Code

```
def double_char(string):
    for i in string:
        # Place code here

def main():
    user_string = input()
    print(double_char(user_string))


main()
```

How can I complete the function *double_char(string)*?

Comment: What exactly have you, yourself, tried so far to meet the requirements? Where are you getting stuck? Stack Overflow **will not** write your code for you, but we *can* assist if you show you’ve undertaken a good-faith attempt on your part before posting here.

Comment: Have a look here => [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```py
user_input = 'hello'

def double_word(s):
    double = ''.join([x+x for x in s])
    return double

print(double_word(user_input))
```

The list comprehension, `[x+x for x in s]` produces this:  `['hh', 'ee', 'll', 'll', 'oo']`

`''.join()` combines the values into a single string.

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked :) Can explain to me the process?

Comment: the list comprehension iterates through the given string, for each element it adds the element to itself.  join, takes all the elements in the generated list, and combines them into a single string.. that string is returned. If this worked for you please accept the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

In case you want to replicate a string several times, let´s say 2, you can do.

```
s = "a"
double_s = s*2
```

Then you can iterate char by char in a string with:

```
for s in my_string:
  # Here I do something with s, like for example duplicate it
```

So mixing both approaches an accumulating the characters once duplicated in a string:

```
def double_char(string):
    res = ""
    for i in string:
        res += i*2
    return res
```

Comment: I'd actually like to repeat every character twice

Comment: @poggeezerking Yeah, I added both pieces of the solution in my answer.

Comment: I edited my question and I do have the for loop, I just dont' know how to duplicate every letter twice

Comment: @poggeezerking there you have it, basically combining both